# PHP: how to create a redirect for multiple files (require, header)?

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a file (config.php) that contains a redirect type header(location:..)

Code config.php:

```
  if($config_is_ok !== true) {
    exit(header('location: install'));
  }
```

Folders structure

```
-localhost
--config.php
--index.php
--install
---index.php
--admin
---index.php
```

In index.php and in admin -> index.php have this code:

```
require_once('../config.php');
... irelevante code ...
```

How can I edit config.php to redirect me properly?
(I tried several methods like that but it didn't work ..)

```
  $website_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]/install";
  if($config_is_ok !== true) {
    exit(header('location: ' . $website_link));
  }
```

I want to use this config.php in several files with the 'require' method but I can't make that header functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current file structure, you are redirecting to a non-existent file, and likely misusing the exit function.  I would recommend

```
  if($config_is_ok !== true) {
    header('location: /install/index.php');
    die;
  }
```

A few other notes to consider:

- Your directory structure needs some work. Things like config and install should *not* be accessible from the document root.
- Does `install/index.php` use config?  Watch out for a recursive reference!
- A little thing: It took me several tries to correctly understand `if($config_is_ok !== true)`. You’re actually testing to see if the config is bad or missing; `if($missing_config) { // redirect }` might be easier to follow.

Comment: but I'm interested in not repeating myself in the code.
That's why I want that code that you wrote in response, to import it with require_once in the admin / index.php file (If I do this, the link in the header.. will be wrong and will only work in the main folder 'localhost')

Comment: please clarify what is the document root

Comment: document root is localhost

Comment: The header will work wherever it’s called. The leading forward slash means relative to document root. Or am I missing the point and you are asking how to do it with a more secure directory structure?

Comment: but the location of the file changes from one 'require_once' to another.
in localhost/index.php header('location: localhost/install') and in localhost/admin/index.php header('location: ../install').

how can I make that location in the header work in both cases?

Comment: refer to my previous comment. `require` is relative to file system; header is relative to url. Starting with the forward slash means start st localhost

Comment: I forgot of slash from the beginning "/" thanks.